# destroy box2d body after collision with delay

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

This is re-question

I want to destroy bodies after collision but with an delay of 4-6 seconds. 
I am successful in detection of collision & destruction of body after collision but now i want a delay in it.

I don't know how to delay.

Answer (score 0):

Make One function which will take B2Body as argument and call that function with delay.

Call function like this:

```
std::vector<b2Body *>::iterator pos; 
for(pos = bodyToDestroy.begin();pos != bodyToDestroy.end(); ++pos){ 
b2Body *body = *pos; 
if(body->GetUserData() != NULL){ 
CCPhysicsSprite *sprite = (CCPhysicsSprite *) body->GetUserData(); 
[sprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
} 
[self performSelector:@selector(myfunc) withObject:body afterDelay:4.0]; 
}
```

And The function will be

```
-(void)myfunc : (b2Body *)body{
    world->destroyBody(body);
}
```

Comment: I am using this code in the update method. So how do i use your solution here std::vector<b2Body *>::iterator pos;
    for(pos = bodyToDestroy.begin();pos != bodyToDestroy.end(); ++pos){
        b2Body *body = *pos;
        if(body->GetUserData() != NULL){
            CCPhysicsSprite *sprite = (CCPhysicsSprite *) body->GetUserData();
            [sprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
        }
        world->DestroyBody(body);
    }

Comment: [self performSelector:@selector(myfunc) withObject:**body **afterDelay:4.0]; incompatible type error at body object

Comment: [self performSelector:@selector(myfunc) withObject:(__bridge id)body afterDelay:4.0]; ,,This might work, i haven't tested yet.

Comment: there is nothing like __bridge id

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30548/discussion-between-jay-gajjar-and-rao27)